# Java file scanner move the cursor back

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using the java scanner class for scanning log file and search for exception then once I find the exception I want to print 20 lines before it and 20 lines after it.
Is there an option to return 20 lines once I found my exception
The code like this.

```
Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
            while(in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
                result = in.nextLine().indexOf(searchString) >= 0;
                if (result)
                {
                    //return 20 lines
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Buffer the lines as you read them. When you find the error, read the next 20 and buffer those also. Then return the buffer.

Comment: What if next 20 lines contain the line author tries to match? In this case algorithm would need to be lot more complex than that.

Comment: I'd assumed he was only interested in the first occurrence. I can only work with what is in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file to a List and use ListIterator.

```
List<String> logList = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));
ListIterator iter = logList.listIterator();
String result = "match string";
while(iter.hasNext() && !result);
int indexMatch = iter.previousIndex();
    // Print previous 20 lines and next 20 lines
    for(int i=-20;i<40;i++){
        System.out.println(logList.get(indexMatch+i));
    } 
}
```